# "function strupr not declared on this scope"

Tags: c, string, function

I'm working on a code, and I tried it in one compiler and everything goes well, but in another it says "function strupr not declared on this scope". I can't understand why this happen.  This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char c,S[100];
    int x=0,i,a,b;
    for(i=0;c!='\n';){
            scanf("%c",&c);
            if (c!=',' && c!=' ' && c!='.' && c!='!' && c!='?'){S[i]=c; i++;}
        }

    while(S[0]!='D' && S[1]!='O' && S[2]!='N' && S[3]!='E'){
        strupr(S);

        for(i=0;S[i]!='\n';i++){}

        for(a=0,b=(i-1); a<=b; a++,b--){
            if (S[a]!=S[b]){x+=1;}
        }
        if (x==0){printf("You won't be eaten!\n");}
        else {printf("Uh oh..\n");}
        c=a;
        x=0;


        for(i=0;c!='\n';){
            scanf("%c",&c);
            if (c!=',' && c!=' ' && c!='.' && c!='!' && c!='?'){S[i]=c; i++;}
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your compiler, at the very least.

Comment: sorry, thats what he say: prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:13:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strupr' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         strupr(S);
         ^

Comment: When it works, what compiler are you using?  On what operating system?  When it fails, what compiler are you using?  On what operating system?

Comment: worked on windows with codeblocks GNU GCC Compiler, and failed on ubuntu with geany gcc compiler and on a online compiler using "C (gcc-4.9.2)".

Answer (score 2):

`strupr()` looks like a Windows-only call.

Comment: what that means? how it should be? i just started learning programming and C

Comment: @FelipeChabatura: It means that you used a function which is not defined by every C compiler (more accurately, by every standard C library).  The functions you can rely on are those in the standard C library -- and not many others.  And, in particular, `strupr()` is not in the standard C library.  It's not hard to write, but if you port code between platforms, this is the sort of thing that happens until you know how to avoid the issues.

Comment: I see, thank you guys , in that code (is a marathon problem) i needed to transform small letters on uppercase letters so i googled and found this function, theres a way i check if others function i found are on default C library?

Comment: The standard conversion facilities for single-byte code sets are declared in `<ctype.h>` and include tests `islower()` and converters `toupper()`.  These work on single characters.  If you're sure you want to case-convert the entire string, then writing the analog of `strupr()` is pretty easy: `char *struprt(char *str) { char *next = str; while (*str != '\0') *str = toupper((unsigned char)*str); return str; }`  Since `toupper()` behaves sanely with non-alpha and already-upper characters, there's no point in testing; it is quicker just to assign.